# В каких случаях использовтать кеширование запросов?

Tags: php, sql, база-данных, кэширование

Возник такой вопрос, в каких случаях лучше использовать кеширования запросов к базе данных?

Если буду использовать его в не больших проектах, будет хоть какая то польза от этого?

Comment: > Если буду использовать его в не больших проектах, будет хоть какая то польза от этого?

Да, в виде опыта.

> Возник такой вопрос, в каких случаях лучше использовать кеширования запросов к базе данных?

Когда им требуется много времени и оптимизировать сам запрос не получается, либо когда посещаемость настолько высока, что 10-50% времени загрузки страницы играют достаточную роль для выявления и ликвидации всех более-менее узких мест

Кэширование (при правильной инвалидации) всегда даст выигрыш, просто время на кодинг не всегда оправдано и не везде есть достаточно оперативы для масштаб. кэш-я

Comment: @Fike пожалуйста сделайте свой комментарий в виде ответа.

Comment: Очевидно, что в тех случаях, когда это необходимо.

Comment: Кому вопрос не угодил? Хороший же.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Цинично: никогда.

Объясняю со своей колокольни: очевидно, кэшировать результаты запросов имеет смысл с тех случаях, когда данные, которые эти запросы отдают, не меняются. А когда это бывает, можно вообще до обращениям к БД не доводить. Например, если речь идёт о динамически генерящихся веб-страницах, которые зависят от очень редко меняющихся данных. Ну так и сгенерите один раз статическую страницу, и отдавайте её as-is до тех пор, пока что-то не поменяется.

А если данные меняются часто, то кэширование запросов мало чем поможет. Нужно думать на другом уровне.

P.S. Другой уровень - это миллионы записей и десятки тысяч запросов, а не виртуальный хостинг за $5 в месяц, само собой.